# To Firebase UID or Token in Firestore DB?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I understand that if I was using my own app server, I should use Token ID as a reference to the user.

If I am using Firestore DB, and to refer to that user's document are based on the UID - will that cause any issue?

For example, with a database structure like this:
 Main ->
 xkljVWSjaDFAXsdSFkjsdf (UID) ->
.....etc

Or would it be better to use the Token ID as a reference?

Is this the "correct" way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm already used **firebase realtime database** on my many projects.

You can store your users data via this structure:

```
Main -> Users -> xkljVWSjaDFAXsdSFkjsdf (UID) -> ...
```

And you can access those data easily and your UID will be always **unique**.

```
String UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

There will be no issue by using UID.

[Refarence Firebase Data Modele](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-data-modeling-939585ade7f4)

Happy Programming.

Answer (score 1):

> Or would it be better to use the Token ID as a reference?

It won't. Using the `uid` is the best practice when it comes to Firebase.

You can get the uid using the following line of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

The token id can be different while the `uid` is always the same.